# Error while moving category in Magento 2 admin panel "There was a category move error"

Tags: magento2, admin-panel

This error occurred while updating category position in admin panel.

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: @Rabi Kant Sinha  try this  https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/fe1045aef103a9ba937837f888e496780bd8c312